# How to access distributed cache file from map and get the data of the file?

Tags: hadoop

I am just trying to access the Distributed cache file from the mapper and trying to set the record(string) from the cache file as the key just to check if i am getting the contents from the cache file(stop.txt),but what i am getting is that the file content of the actual file which is the input file(input.txt) contents as the key.Please guide
Both the cache file and the input file are in the hdfs

Below is my actual code

```
package com.cache;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.hadoop.filecache.DistributedCache;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityReducer;

public class DistributedCacheTest  {

    public static class MyMap extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable,Text , Text, IntWritable>{

        public Path[] localArchives;
        public Path[] localFiles;
        BufferedReader cacheReader;

        public void configure(JobConf job){
             // Get the cached archives/files
             try {
                localArchives = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheArchives(job);
                 localFiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(job);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
              }


    public void map(LongWritable  key,Text value ,
            OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter report)
            throws IOException {

        if (localFiles != null && localFiles.length > 0) {
             System.out.println("Inside setup(): "
             + localFiles[0].toString());

             String line;
             try{
             cacheReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(localFiles[0].toString()));
             while((line=cacheReader.readLine())!=null)
             {
                 System.out.println("**********" + line);
                 output.collect(new Text(line), new IntWritable(1));
             }
             }
             catch(Exception ex)
             {
                 ex.printStackTrace();
             }
             finally
             {
                 cacheReader.close();
             }



    }
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException, URISyntaxException {
         if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: MaxTemperature <input path> <output path>");
            System.exit(-1);
            }
         JobConf job =new JobConf(DistributedCacheTest.class);
         job.setJobName("DistriTestjob");
         DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("/user/hadoop/stop.txt"),job);

         job.setMapperClass(MyMap.class);
         job.setReducerClass(IdentityReducer.class);

         job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
            job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

            JobClient.runJob(job);


    }

}
```

Comment: try fully qualifying the cache file path (`hdfs://host:port/user/hadoop/stop.txt`)

Comment: Are you able to read the cache file in map.Is the cacheReader.readLine() reaing the cache files?

Comment: Thank you chris for your tip its working...and yes i am able to access cache using readline, working more on that and will let you know once done.

Comment: @arun:The code above outputs the record of the cache file as the key along with some value, in this case im not worried about the values.The main idea is to confirm if the cache file contents is accessible through my code.In this case it is,also remember to give input file having very few 5 to 10 records  as the while loop runs for every record,cache file path (hdfs://host:port/user/hadoop/stop.txt)should be considered at job level while adding distributed cache file.As i said just testing for cache file..Thanks..